What is the "CleanUp" badge?
I wondered about what was the Cleaup badge. In the explanation of this badge it says: First rollback; English is not my mothertongue and I do not understand what it means.
Moreover, can you explain how can you get that?

You get it for doing this: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/17038/what-is-a-rollback

Ok @BobJansen! Got it! Thanks for the answer!

@BobJansen is this an answer embedded in a comment? haha.

@SRKX the software thought my answer was too trivial and converted it immediately :/
